# Could not find or load main class, after build by gradle

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, gradle

I've made a project in **maven** and spring boot. After build it via maven it **worked** perfect.
After all I decided to swap my project into gradle. And now, after:

```
gradle build
```

The following exception is comming.Error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

Here are things I checked before I asked this question:

- made sure that I have main method (which i obviously have, maven did thing great)
- checked path to main class in manifest and in jar task in gradle
- found out that compiled class is in specified jar in specified path
- Made a jar task in gradle that looks like this:

  ```
  jar {
    manifest {
      attributes 'Main-Class': 'pl.sygnity.schedulein.App'
    }
  }
  ```

I have no idea what i can do more about it.
Could you help me?

Edit.
It's important i wish to use my program as jar so:

```
java -jar xx.jar
```

Edit2.

```
gradle run
```

makes my App start. So it looks like as if gradle build is not working somehow...

Comment: Before swap into gradle, did `java -jar xx.jar` worked ?

Comment: Yes it did. With maven i was able to run my program just like that.

Comment: Could you post your whole `build.gradle` file or at least more parts of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your gradle manifest.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes <...>
                   'Main-Class': 'main.myMainClass'
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can change the path of your source fields like this.

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['MAINFOLDER'] // 'src'
```

Comment: I had jar task defined just like this (i modified to question to underline this), and 'other wise' tip didn't help

Comment: I get an error .  
 unexpected token: < @ line 29, column 16.
         attributes <...>
                    ^

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the main class in the build.gradle file. (You may have more than one, and you need to choose which one to use)

I like to do it with [Gradle - the application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "<Your main class>"
```

Then you can run `gradle install` to build the program with an executor.

Comment: Thanks for reply, it actually changed no thing :)

Comment: after you run `gradle install` you will have a directory `build/install/<project name>/bin` with 2 executables having the project name (one for windows and on for linux/mac)

Comment: As I mentioned above in question, i'm into running my app like java -jar xx.jar, project requirements. But the fact is, that when i run .bat file i have my spring run.

Answer (score 0):

So i find out that these steps made my jar working well.

Removed

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

Added

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
```

Bit weird but maybe someone will be struggling with same kind of problem. Thanks for help.